# how to covert regular expression in simplest form?

Tags: regex, nfa

I have made this expression from nfa (NFA to regular expression) :

```
(a+ab+aa*b)*(a+a*a)
```

but at book answers it is written like this :

```
(a+aa*b)*(a+a*a)
```

I am thinking that the my answer is same as book but they have converted it into it just like quadratic equation as we do. SO any one who can help me or book answer is wrong or mine is wrong?
[image]

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com as well, where you're more likely to find info about formal regular expression (see [their related tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions)). Regex in programming aren't usually regular anymore.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se]

Comment: ok robin has told me.

Comment: If at all, this rather should be moved to [cs.SE] than maths

Comment: What is this `γ` character?

Comment: it is NULL and we refer it as null string in theory of automata.

Answer (score 1):

your answer can produce string `aba` that is not valid according to the DFA.